# Error in q() : argument "a" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I am experiencing the following error as I try to quit/close R. Any help on how to sort it.

Error in q() : argument "a" is missing, with no default

Comment: Or use `base::q()`

Comment: Or Ctrl-D, Ctrl-D. Typing `q("no")` is way too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have defined a function to the name `q` so that when you try to quit with `q()` R checks your local environment for a function of that name first and finds one expecting an argument `a1`.

It appears that some comments have been deleted but you have three options.

#### 1. Specify the package

i.e. use `base::q()` so that R does not check your local environment first. (All credit to @Frank.)

#### 2. Try `quit()`

They both do the same thing and it would be unlikely that you named a function `q()` and another `quit()`.

#### 3. Remove `q` from the environment first

`remove(q)` will clear any objects named `q` in your environment so that when you use `q()` R will quit correctly. This will cause issues if you are saving your session info for later.

Comment: Hello everybody. Thanks a lot for your help. It has worked well. I am very grateful.